# AWS (S3) - Github - Vue: Trigger a build depending on which branch changed

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, vuejs2, aws-amplify

So, I am new to all this cloud deployment stuff but I would like to achieve a relatively simple thing:

I have a github repo with a VueJS app... there are 2 branches: **master** / **develop**
I have two AWS s3 buckets where I need to deploy a built app (let's say **myapp-dev** and **myapp-prod**)

As a developer I would like to push my changes to either of the branches...
And then I would have another two s3 buckets like **myapp-src-tmp-dev** and **myapp-src-tmp-prod**, which they would sync up with the github repo

as soon as they sync up, the npm run build would be ran... and the app would be built to the myapp-dev por myapp-prod buckets...

What do I need for the easiest pipeline stack? Do I need amplify or can I do this in some other, faster/ quicker way?

Any good tutorials out there? I was looking but could not find (as I said, new, don't even know how to look)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like AWS Amplify does exactly what I need